# Creating a SQL create table command ensuring that a graph table is undirected

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

Consider a schema with the following relation:

$R(a: int, b : int)$

An instance of this schema is said to be $R$-undirected if for each row $r$ in $R$ within the instance,
there is a row $r′$ in $R$ in the instance with $r′.a$ = $r.b$ and $r′.b$ = $r.a$

I'm trying to create a SQL create table command that ensures that the instance is $R$-undirected (while not restricting the data otherwise)

My idea was the following:

```
CREATE TABLE R(
   a int,
   b int,
   PRIMARY KEY (a,b),
   FOREIGN KEY (a,b) 
   references R(b,a)
)
```

but I'm not sure if this is correct as we can never insert data into this table because of the referential constraint? Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Hi - do you mean table rather than schema? Given that relational DBs and  graphs are very different, and you are asking for a relational DB solution, you may get more responses if you just ask your question/give your requirements in plain English rather than in what I assume is R/Graph notation